# iOS - Get Info.plist file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, plist

I have a method that loads data from the Info.plist file of an app. Right now I'm hardcoding the name and the type, i.e. using `pathForResource`however, this approach fails if the name of the plist file has changed, say MyAppSettings.plist Is there a way I can get the info.plist file that is being used regardless of the name? Thanks

Answer (score 8):

The main App settings file, mostly named `MyApp-info.plist`, will al ways be named `info.plist` after the app is compiled and bundled.

There is also a short way to acces the `info.plist`:

```
NSNumber *version =  [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```